# HP Envy m4 unable to toggle wifi hardware switch

Tags: networking, drivers, hp

I am on an HP Envy m4 running 18.04 and unable to turn on wifi. In the notification bar in the upper right-hand corner of the screen, I read "Airplane mode on" and "use hardware switch to turn off." This is a recent problem -- I have had a working installation for some time. The only recent updates on my machine have been system updates of libparted, firefox.

We see here that there is indeed a hard block on wireless:

> > rfkill list all
>
> 0: phy0: Wireless LAN
> Soft blocked: no
> Hard blocked: yes

There is a wifi switch on my laptop's F12 key, but as I understand there are no linux drivers for this, so there is no response for this button.

I have reset the BIOS and have checked that the leads of the wireless card were properly connected. When I run Ubuntu on liveUSB the same issue persists. Solutions to similar questions using modprobe have not worked for me. Ideally, I would put in a new wireless card and see what happens, but I'd like to try and rule out other problems before I do this.

Answer (score 0):

"Hard blocked" means that there is a PHYSICAL SWITCH in the "OFF" position. You can't fix it via software.

Others have had this problem, see [https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Wireless-and-Networking/Where-is-wireless-button-on-HP-ENVY-all-in-one/td-p/5677496](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Wireless-and-Networking/Where-is-wireless-button-on-HP-ENVY-all-in-one/td-p/5677496%20%22this%20link%22Wireless-and-Networking/Where-is-wireless-button-on-HP-ENVY-all-in-one/td-p/5677496)

From the solution linked above:

> I am certain that my keyboard is different than yours, but I have to
>   press the "fn" key at the bottom of the keyboard and the "F12" key at
>   the same time.  This will turn my wifi off and on.  You may have to
>   use a different key with the fn key.

Comment: Your link is "page not found".

Comment: Hi, thanks for your interest. My laptop indeed has the F12 button with a wifi icon as you describe. However, this has never had any effect in Ubuntu -- with or without Fn button, there is no toggling of wifi that happens when pressed.

Comment: I should maybe add that the keypress does register, while > nmcli radio wifi on (which I think is what the keypress is supposed to do) has no effect.